# Syntax for using LG templates/functions within adaptive expressions in Bot Framework Composer

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer

I want to set a property using an expression as follows:  `=json(InputCard(dialog.msgs))`

where InputCard() is an LG template (shown below).  I get the following error:

> Expression evaluation resulted in an error. Expression: "=json(InputCard(dialog.msgs))". Error: InputCard does not have an evaluator, it's not a built-in function or a custom function.

Is there a syntax which allows me to use an LG template in an adaptive expression or is this not possible? Thanks for any suggestions.

In case it is relevant, the definition of #InputCard is as follows:

````
# InputCard(msgs)
- ```
{
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "version": "1.2",
  "body": [
  {
    "type": "FactSet",
    "facts": [
      ${join(foreach(msgs,item,FactGen(item.key,item.value)), ',' ) } 
    ]
  },
    {
      "type": "Input.Text",
      "id": "reply",
      "placeholder": "Enter your reply here"
    }
  ],
  "actions": [
    {
      "type": "Action.Submit",
      "title": "Submit",
      "data": ${json(msgs)}
    }
  ],
  "msteams": {"width": "Full"}
}
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to install the [Bot Framework Adaptive Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BotBuilder.bot-framework-adaptive-tools) for Visual Studio Code.

Once you do you'll get highlighting and a message like this when you hover the squiggly line:

[image]

I guess the problem is that you haven't used the [namespace and exports LG options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/file-format/bot-builder-lg-file-format?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#exports-option) in the template where you define "FactGen" and "InputCard"

**UPDATE**: Pasted the correct link above

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response, that works perfectly!